# A different criterion for equivalence of codes?

Tags: coding-theory

I've been thinking about equivalence of codes (two codes that are equal up to order of positions of the letters, or permutations of the letters in a fixed position).

It is obvious that if we have two codes with the same distance $d$, it doesn't mean they are equivalence; nor if they have the same set of distances.

However, I thought about listing the distances and counting them, that is, make a list of the type "there are $n_1$ pairs of words in the code with distance $1$, $n_2$ pairs of words that differ only in two positions, $n_3 \ldots$"

It is not difficult to see that this criterion does not imply equivalence if we talk about ternary codes; but what if we take binary codes? I have a gut feeling it's wrong too, but can't think of a counter example.

Comment: Yes. This is the case. There are known families of relatively simple extended cyclic codes that are known to be non-equivalent, but nevertheless have identical weight enumerators. I will look for a reference, when I am back in my office.

Comment: By "simple" I mean that the number of zeros of a cyclic code was either two or three. The lengths of these are powers of two $\ge 64$ (IIRC) or one less.

Comment: Here's the link http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=255876.255880

It is a bit embarassing that I didn't remember this right away. My firstborn graduate student worked on their decoding (among other things).

Answer (score 4):

In the case of linear codes, this is the same as asking for non-equivalent codes with the same weight enumerator.  There are many examples known.  Search for "same weight enumerator" at google scholar and you'll find some examples quickly.

For example, [this paper](http://www.springerlink.com/content/hj40064667223702/) and [this one](http://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eruudp/paper/57.pdf) and [this one](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/748461) and [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9310227.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I looked it up and couldn't find anything; it's possible that I did find but couldn't understand it (I only know the basics of coding theory).

Comment: I added some links.

Comment: Thanks. I can only open the second and fourth links, and I don't really see the connection, but I'll have a closer look shortly.

Answer (score 4):

- An example of two $(n,M)$ codes that have the same distance enumerator, but
  not necessarily the same weight enumerator is any two cosets of a $[n,\log_2(M)]$ linear
  code.  Thus, the $(2,2)$ codes with codewords $\{00, 11\}$ and $\{01,10\}$ respectively
  have the same distance enumerator but not the same weight enumerator. Obviously
  the codes cannot be equivalent under a permutation of coordinates.
- An example of two codes with the same weight enumerator but different
  distance enumerators is the pair of $(3,3)$ codes with codewords
  $\{110, 100, 010\}$ and $\{110, 100, 001\}$ respectively.  Both have weight enumerator
  $2z+z^2$ but the codes are not equivalent under permutation of coordinates.
- An example of inequivalent linear codes with identical weight enumerators (and
  thus identical distance enumerators) is 
  the $[32,16]$ 2nd-order Reed-Muller (RM) code and the $[32,16]$ extended quadratic residue
  (QR) code. These codes are not equivalent under permutation of coordinates.  The RM code 
  has $155$ cosets that have $8$ coset leaders of weight $4$ while the QR code
  has no such cosets. In fact, cosets of the QR code that have coset leaders of weight 
  $4$ have at most $5$ such coset leaders. The details are in Chapter 8 of my 
  unpublished Ph.D. thesis
  "Weight Enumerators of Reed-Muller Codes and Cosets" Princeton University, 1973.

Comment: That's a nice one (+1). I was half expecting something longer.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow!  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.07.18

Comment: Hmm. I rather like the third example only. While it may fit the scope of the question, going for a coset feels like cheating. As does a code with one component always zero.

Comment: Sorry about being a bit cranky here. I cannot get rid of my preconceived notion of the "correct" version of this question, and only the third (or chronologically the first) example is a good match with that.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two inequivalent binary codes with the same distance enumerator. Code A consists of the codewords $a=00000000000$, $b=11110000000$, $c=11111111100$, $d=11000110011$; code R consists of the codewords $r=0000000000$, $s=1111000000$, $t=0111111111$, $u=1000111100$. Writing $xy$ for the Hamming distance between words $x$ and $y$, we have $ab=rs=4$, $bc=ru=5$, $cd=tu=6$, $ac=rt=9$, and  $ad=bd=st=su=7$, so the distance enumerators are identical. But code A has the 7-7-4 triangle $adb$, while code R has the 7-7-6 triangle $tsu$, so there is no distance-preserving bijection between the two codes.

I'm sure there are shorter examples.

EDIT: a much shorter example: Code A consists of the codewords $a=000$, $b=100$, $c=011$, $d=111$; code R consists of the codewords $r=0000$, $s=1000$, $t=0100$, $u=0011$. Both codes have two pairs of words at each of the distances 1, 2, and 3; R has a 1-1-2 triangle, A doesn't.

MORE EDIT: In response to Jyrki's objections, here's one where both codes are of the same length, and no component is constant over all code words. $a=0000$, $b=1000$, $c=1110$, $d=1111$; $r=0000$, $s=0111$, $t=1110$, $u=1111$. Each code has two pairs at distance 1 and two at distance 3, and one each at distances 2 and 4; first code has a 1-3-4 triangle, $abd$, second code doesn't.

Comment: Hmm. Am I counting something wrong? I see $d(a,d)=d(b,d)=6$. Also using codes of different length feels like cheating, because the question of equivalence becomes meaningless.

Comment: different length - may be add zeroes at the end will cure ?

Comment: Sorry about being a bit cranky here. I cannot get rid of my preconceived notion of the "correct" version of this question :-)

Comment: @Jyrki, you're right about the distances in the first example. I'll have to check my notes to see what I really meant to say. But I think I got the distances right in the second example. And I did have Alexander's idea in mind for the lengths; take 0000, 1000, 0110, 1110 for Code A, and it's the same length as Code R. I don't know why you feel that a code with one component constant is cheating, but I'll edit in an example without that feature. 